# Will i get a Multiple OS boot choice after installing Ubuntu with Windows 7?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, bios

I have Windows 7 operating off an HDD and am going to install Ubuntu on to another seperate HDD.

How will I determine the boot options? through Bios by the HDD each time I start, or is there a bit of software that ubuntu installs that allows me to choose which OS to boot when I turn the computer on after the bios runs it's checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Traditional Install (through bootable USB/DVD)**

If you install from a bootable disc or USB stick, if everything goes correctly (which is the case 99% of the time for most computers/laptops), you'll get a `bootloader` option right after the `BIOS` screen.

This is called `Grub`, which is the default `bootloader` for Ubuntu. From there you'll be able to choose between the different OS's installed in the different partitions and/or disks on your computer.

Basically, `Grub` will be written into somewhere in the first 100 GB sector (the `MBR`, or Master Boot Record) of your hard disk (if there are multiple disks, the `BIOS` will look based on the boot order configured in the `BIOS` settings). The `BIOS` will be looking for a bootloader there, find `Grub`, which will let you choose as mentioned above.

Just make sure you don't end up wiping the partition where Windows 7 is currently residing. There's an option during install that does the partitioning and stuff for you automatically, so it shouldn't be a problem :)

**Wubi Install (not recommended)**

When installing using the `Wubi` method, Ubuntu is installed similar as an application while you're in Windows 7. It creates a virtual disk image and puts all the necessary files in there.

In this case you'll get the Windows `bootloader`. Far more inferior than `Grub` in many ways. A lot of people also have problems with `Wubi` installations (whether it's during or after the install, bad stuff happens almost all the time). *So I strongly discourage you from going this route!*

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, just one question, does grub have to be on the mbr of the first drive on the sata 1 port so it can be accessed when the bios boot sequence is set to boot from that drive? OR dosnt it matter if grub resides on the secoond sata drives MBR, and it will find it still.... or should i always boot first from the drive with grub on the mbr forst? Reason i ask is because i want to keep windows 7 OS on the First SATA port on it's own drive.  hope that question made sense. you have been a great help so far.

Comment: Well as mentioned, the `BIOS` settings will allow you to choose the order of the search for a bootloader (i.e. boot order). I recommend you put `Grub` in the MBR of the first possible disk your `BIOS` will choose, since it is a much better bootloader than the Windows loader, and will have no problem booting into Windows.

Comment: Ok, So just point the BIOS to boot from SATA 2 so i can use the grub boot tool.  then just select window.s

Comment: Ok thanks again. so make bios boot from sata 2 (ubuntu) and the grub tool will come up and boot from there.  thanks for your help, every question i have asked has been answered do well.  appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Doing those things, you should be able to boot into both Ubuntu and Windows by choice from Grub. Unless the Windows bootloader is broken somehow, which shouldn't happen!